# Git - bare repo, is checkout on a different working-tree and submodules working?

Tags: git, web-deployment, git-submodules, git-bare

On my production server I created a bare repo and a working directory.
This in order to have history in a unusual place while the working directory is "public". Everything seems fine even if I'm thinking about having misunderstood "bare" and used instead of a "swallow" one.

However I saw a strange behaviour of git using the combination of "bare repo" and "submodules".

Apparently submodules are not in the git repo.
However after every deploy checkout to selected commit... they just work fine.
However as they are not tracked I cannot check the status of them.

```
git status
On branch web
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/develop'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

But... If I run the same command for modules:

```
git submodule status
fatal: git-submodule cannot be used without a working tree.
```

Is this normal?

This is making me thinking about disband all the setup and create a standard non-bare repo instead (maybe lightweight with `depth=1`).

Do I misunderstood further something else?
Is my setup a good security practice or a useless effort?

Comment: You need to be a lot more explicit here: *I created a bare repo and a working directory.* The definition of "bare repository" is "one that has no working directory", so if you have a working directory, you don't have a bare repository. So what, *precisely*, did you do? What exact steps will reproduce this situation on another machine, so that someone else can see it occur? (See also [ask].)

Comment: Just what i said. I first create a bare repo in a protected directory. Then I checkout the bare report in a working directory with `git --work-tree=/path/to/outputdir checkout master`

Comment: OK. And then, while still in the bare repository protected directory, you ran `git status`? And the command you used to *create* the bare repository was `git init --bare`?  Or was it `git clone --bare <url>`, or was it something else entirely? Was there a `chdir` command afterward?

Comment: the output above is `git --work-tree=/path/to/outputdir status` within the protected directory. The command used to create was just `git init --bare` on a empty dir. Then I added remote 'origin' repo, fetch from origin, create a local empty branch that track the branch i want (master, or develop it depends if it's the production system or not), and then I checkout in the working directory. Since 5 years everything is working great. I just realise that from there I cannot track any changes  on the submodules. They just don't exists in the repo, while in the working directory they are there.

Comment: Well, my point in these comments is that *all of the above commands should have been in the original question* in order to provide a way for others to reproduce the problem. You, instead, showed a simple `git status`, not `git --work-tree=... status`. Now, consider what happens if you use `git --work-tree=... submodule status` (and/or with other submodule commands). If that works, great. If not, show what happens with *those* commands too.

Comment: Both of them use --work-tree but one works, the other one no.
Sometime work-tree is buggy and is preferred EXPORT the var the ENV bash.
This works better... and this is why those command i reported doesn't have --work-tree, but 'should' be the same with or with ENV EXPORT of `GIT_WORK_TREE`.
https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables

Comment: That, too, is fine: but if testing product X requires standing on your head, you must *include that in the instructions*. If you intend for others to be able to reproduce your issue, and it's necessary to export particular env variables, **include that in your question**! We are not watching you run commands; we cannot see anything other than what you tell us.

Comment: @torek this is true